# Correlation problems with two variables WITH NA

Tags: r, correlation, na

I have two variables and I want to know if they are correlated, I have them distributed like this:

`X = 14,15,16,18,12,13,14,15` 
`Y = NA, 13,12, NA, NA, 16,16, NA`

And when by

`cor(X, Y)`

NA

Comment: Are you aware that `X` has 8 elements, while `Y` only has 6?

Comment: Sorry, its NA, 13,12,NA,NA,16,16,NA

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate omitting all points for which `NA` appears in even one of either `X` or `Y`, then you can call `cor()` with the option `use='complete.obs'`:

```
X <- c(14, 15, 16, 18, 12, 13, 14, 15)
Y <- c(NA, 13, 12, NA, NA, 16, 16, NA)

cor(X, Y, use='complete.obs', method='pearson')
[1] -0.9393364
```

You can verify for yourself that the above result is the same as using:

```
X <- c(15, 16, 13, 14)
Y <- c(13, 12, 16, 16)
cor(X, Y, method='pearson')
```

i.e. just dropping those data points for which either `X` or `Y` has an `NA` value.